# how to sort by three elements

Tags: javascript, sorting, element

Regarding this link: http://jsfiddle.net/De8Ku/1477/ How to develop the code so that I can sort by rating for example?

```
    var vA = parseInt($(keySelector, a).text().replace("$",''));
    var vB = parseInt($(keySelector, b).text().replace("$",''));

    return (vA < vB) ? -1 : (vA > vB) ? 1 : 0;
```

Comment: Your code is working perfect... [Just updated the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/De8Ku/2459/)

Answer (score 0):

Add some ratings, for example...

```
<a href="#">
    <span class="alpha">D</span>
    <span class="price">$35</span>
    <span class="rating">1.3</span>
</a>
```

Add a link...

```
<li>
    <a href="#" id="sRating" class="btnSort">
        Rating
    </a>
</li>
```

Add a data attribute to the link to tell it to sort by the selector `span.rating`...

```
$('#sRating').data("sortKey", "span.rating");
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/deA7G/)